# Open datepicker when input is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this input type date in here and currently, the datepicker will only show once the user clicks the arrow down button in its field. What I want to happen is that, open the datepicker every time the user clicks the input field.

```
<input type="date" id="date_of_purchase" name="date_of_purchase" class="input-field input-date" placeholder="Inköpsdatum">
```

Comment: the code you posted is not enough to say where the problem is. Please post more information about js libraries you are using and look at your console error log

Comment: I am not using any Javascript libraries.

Comment: so how do you aspect the datepicker comes up?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using jQuery for this. It has way more options en configuration for things like this. You don't have a lot influence on the HTML default `type="date"`.

Comment: Are you trying to open a Jquery datepicker on textbox click?

Comment: I just used the default datepicker of HTML and currently, they will only show the datepicker once you will click the arrow down button of the input. But, I want to show the datepicker everytime the user clicks the input

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I'm not using any Javascript libraries but I want to open the datepicker on input click

Comment: Opening a datepicker si not the default behavior of HTML. Maybe some browser ca do it, but you need some js library to do that

Comment: @DaFois Ohh I see. Gonna use a javascript library then.

Comment: Bit surprised after reading your comment! As I know there is not any option to open datepicker without third party library its better to use jQuery or any moments.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [jQuery UI page for datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

[Creating a datepicker with fall back on jquery](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/30/creating-a-native-html5-datepicker-with-a-fallback-to-jquery-ui/)

Comment: Isn't there a way to solve this without using a javascript library?

Comment: I see. I'll use this solution then. Thanks! :)