# Open datepicker on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this input field I can open calendar only on icon next to input field, I want to open calendar on whole input field. How can I do this?

```html
   <link  rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.2.0/css/datepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.2.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script>
    function exportbydate() {
        swal({
            title: "{{trans('a_pdf.choosedate')}}",
            html: `<form action="{{ url('/myaccount/view/transfer/pdf') }}" method="GET">`+
                `<div class="row">

                <input id="fromdate" name="fromdate" class="form-control" type="date" placeholder="Your name here" style="margin:10px; width: 50%;" autocomplete="off" required/>

               <input id="todate" name="todate" class="form-control" type="date"  style="margin:10px; width: 50%" autocomplete="off" required/>
                </div>`+
                ` <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >{{trans('a_pdf.search')}}</button>`+
                `</form>`,
            width: '650px',
            showCancelButton: false,
            showConfirmButton: false,
            showCloseButton: true,


        })
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Try this maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896240/open-datepicker-when-input-is-clicked

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
```

```html
<!-- Using jQuery UI Datepicker -->

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know like this, but it doesnt work with html code that is inside of swal().